# in R: loop over multiple input files and save the results file according the name of each input file

Tags: r, list, loops, data-analysis

I'm a beginner with R. 
I would need your help to automate these analyses over all the files contained in the list "scores" (~50 files) and get (and save) a summary output with the results corresponding to each of the input file (summary output to be named similarly to each input file).

Now, with my code (attached) I can get the results for one input file at a time. For example, if I consider the second element of the list named "scores":

```
    file.names <- dir(pattern ="*.my.files") ### set the pattern name of the input files
    scores<-list() ### create a variable (list) that will contain the input data 
    for (k in 1:length(file.names)){scores[[k]] <- read.table(file.names[k],h=T)}

    ### scores[[2]] is the second element of the list named "scores"
    f1<-function(threshold) { glm(pheno ~ threshold + PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 +PC5 +PC6 +PC7+ PC8 + PC9 + C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9, family='binomial',data=scores[[2]]) }


    m1<-apply(scores[[2]][2:9],2,f1) ### scores[[2]] is the second element of the list named "scores", 
                                     ###    the columns from 2 to 9 corresponds to the scores at the different p thresholds
                                     ###    after the first comma --> MARGIN: a vector giving the subscripts which the function 
                                     ###    will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, 
                                     ###    c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns. Where X has named dimnames, it can be a character vector 
                                     ###    selecting dimension names.

    ### calculate OR and R2:
    out1<-do.call(rbind,lapply(m1,function(z)summary(z)$coefficients[2,]))
    out1<-data.frame(out1)
    out1$OR<-exp(out1$Estimate)
    out1$ci_l<-exp(out1$Estimate-(1.96 * out1$Std..Error))
    out1$ci_u<-exp(out1$Estimate+(1.96 * out1$Std..Error))

    write.table(out1, file="estimates.txt", quote=F, sep=" ", dec=".", na="NA", row.names=T, col.names=T)

    ### calculate nagelkerkeR2: 
    library(sizeMat)
    full.nagel.r2<-do.call(rbind,lapply(m1,function(z)nagelkerkeR2(z)))
    full.nagel.r2<-data.frame(full.nagel.r2)
    n1<-glm(as.factor(pheno) ~ PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 +PC5 +PC6 +PC7+ PC8 + PC9 + C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9, family='binomial',data=scores[[2]]) # null model
    full.nagel.r2$prs.r2<-full.nagel.r2[,1] - nagelkerkeR2(n1)

    write.table(full.nagel.r2, file="variance.txt", quote=F, sep=" ", dec=".", na="NA", row.names=T, col.names=T)
```

I was also wondering if I could merge the results of the "estimate.txt" and "variance.txt" files in order to get a single output file for each input file of the list named "scores".

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Paul, your example is way too long.  You need to boil it down to a *single* *simple* problem. Please make a Minimal Reproducible Example.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 .  You _must_ include some sample data 4-10 lines; is usually enough. Include a sample of what you want the output to look like.  Don't include images or  links to outside data source.  We want to help you, but you've got to work with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply generalize your process with a data frame input or build a named list of data frames and iterate off names for distinct `.txt` files. Below shows how `lapply` can handle your iteration and data handling needs:

```
library(sizeMat)
...

# BUILD NAMED LIST OF DATA FRAMES
file.names <- dir(pattern ="*.my.files")
scores <- setNames(lapply(file.names, read.table, header=TRUE),
                   gsub(".my.files", "", file.names))

# DEFINED FUNCTION RECEIVING DF NAME PARAM
proc_scores <- function(df_name) {
   df <- scores[[df_name]]

   models <- lapply(df, function(threshold) {
       glm(pheno ~ threshold + PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4+PC5+PC6+PC7+PC8+PC9 + C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9, 
           family='binomial', data=df)
   })

   ### calculate OR and R2:
   coeff_mat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(models, function(z) summary(z)$coefficients[2,]))
   coeff_df <- transform(data.frame(coeff_mat), 
      OR = exp(Estimate),
      ci_l = exp(Estimate - (1.96 * Std..Error)),
      ci_u = exp(Estimate + (1.96 * Std..Error)),
      score = df_name
  )

   # SAVE OUTPUT WITH DATA FRAME NAME
   write.table(coeff_df, file=paste0("estimates_", df_name, "_.txt"), quote=FALSE, 
               sep=" ", dec=".", na="NA", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)


   ### calculate nagelkerkeR2
   null.model <- glm(as.factor(pheno) ~ PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4+PC5+PC6+PC7+PC8+PC9 + C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9, 
                     family='binomial', data=df)

   nagel_mat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(models, function(z) nagelkerkeR2(z)))
   nagel_df <- data.frame(nagel_mat)
   nagel_df$prs.r2 <- nagel_df[,1] - nagelkerkeR2(null.model)
   nagel_df$score <- df_name

   # SAVE OUTPUT WITH DATA FRAME NAME
   write.table(nagel_df, file=paste0("variance_", df_name,"_.txt"), quote=FALSE, 
               sep=" ", dec=".", na="NA", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)

   # RETURN LIST OF DATA FRAMES
   return(list(coeff=coeff_df, nagel=nagel_df))
}


# ITERATELY CALL FUNCTION
results <- lapply(names(scores), proc_scores)
```

Since process exports data to `.txt` and returns the same objects in list, you can access them accordingly:

```
results[[1]]$coeff
results[[2]]$coeff   
results[[3]]$coeff
...

results[[1]]$nagel
results[[2]]$nagel
results[[3]]$nagel
...
```

For master compilation of results:

```
master_coeff <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, "[[", "coeff"))

# SAVE OUTPUT
write.table(master_coeff, file="estimates.txt", quote=FALSE, sep=" ",
            dec=".", na="NA", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)


master_nagel <- do.call(rbind, lapply(results, "[[", "nagel"))

# SAVE OUTPUT
write.table(master_nagel, file="variance.txt", quote=FALSE, 
            sep=" ", dec=".", na="NA", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```